# What is the equivalent of PostgreSQL @> operator in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using PostgreSQL database for a program and came across the [*contains range* (`@>`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html) operator.

As I am converting a PostgreSQL query in python SQLAlchemy, therefore, I need to convert `@>` into its SQLAlchemy equivalent.

Comment: You only told to improve the question. This time I tried to be Specific and one point

Comment: Have you had a look at using the generic `op()`: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.Operators.op? I'm sure GeoAlchemy would offer types and functions that have proper python equivalents of the PostGIS ops, but the generic will get you past your current hurdle.

Comment: I will try and get back.

Comment: It failed. I tried this: Places.query.filter(loc_amsterdam.in_(loc_company)) . The in_ operator

Comment: But got an error

Comment: Finally did it. Thank You.

Answer (score 11):

I used [`op()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.Operators.op). The operator `@>` is equivalent to "in" in python. But similar results could be achieved using `.op('@>')` through SQLAlchemy. For example:

```
Places.query.filter(loc_amsterdam.op("@>")(loc_company))
```

Comment: Ok, this is much better - a self-answered short question with a correct answer.